# script to map network drive depending on your location in domain sites

Tags: vbscript

I'm using scripts to map network drives in domain. We have 2 sites with 2 public drives, one in each. 
So what I'm trying to do is to have a script to map one of the public drives depending on your location.

If you're in location 1, map \\server1\public as P drive and remove Z drive if exists. If you're in location 2, map \\server2\public as Z drive. and remove P drive is exists.

location 1 uses 192.168.0-1.x and subnet 255.255.254.0
location 2 uses 192.168.3.x and subnet 255.255.255.0

It can use IP or subnet to check for location but I don't know how to do that.
I checked with other group and they don't recommend scripts, they suggested using AD for doing so but I want to see how both options work.

This is what we use now to map drives: `net use P: \\server2\public`.

Comment: Assign different logon scripts per site via GPO. Or do different drive mappings per site via GPP.

Comment: Ok, so I created a test GPO and linked it to an OU and only added a test user to it that way it doesn't apply to everyone while I'm testing but the drives are not showing when I log in with the test user. I did gpupdate /force and restarted like 20 times but no luck.

What am I messing here?

My DC is windows 2012 R2

clients are windows 10

added the mapped drives under "User Configuration > Preferences > Windows Setting > Drive Maps" 

I also added the test user name under the Targeting Editor but that did not help either.

Comment: Use `rsop.msc` to analyze which policies actually apply to that user on a given computer. This goes into infrastructure management territory, though, so you may want to ask about it on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 0):

We run 15 Sites here with a Distrubited Location, X: = \SiteServer\"Public Folder"
If you have AD, set it up with 2 sites (Different sites with there correct IP Ranges), create a DFS System (Free on Windows Server), then you can just MAP to the \DomainName\"Public Folder" and it will map to the LOCAL SVR Record (File Server onsite).

Comment: Please post your question separately, not as part of an answer.